# Java Array column and row numbering

Tags: java, arrays

Im new to programming and hopefully can get some guidance, I searched for clues but have had no luck.
I wrote the code for  a two dimensional array, my problem is that i cannot get the row and column numbers to show along with the elements...this is the closest i have come
now output is;

```
  T F F T F F 
0 F F T F F T 
1 F T F F T F 
2 T F F T F F 
3 F F T F F T 
4 F T F F T F 
5
```

I need output to be;

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 T F F T F F 
1 F F T F F T 
2 F T F F T F 
3 F F T F F T
4 F T F F T F
5 T F F T F T
```

Here's the code:
public class Array {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("  ");
    boolean [][] a;
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    a = new boolean [N][N];
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j<a[0].length;j++){
            a[i][j] = true; 
            int sum = (i+j);

            if (sum%3==0) {
               System.out.print(   "T " );
            } else {
               System.out.print(  "F ");
            }
   }
         System.out.println();
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
     }
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Pro tip: You definitely should reformat your code so that it's properly indented, has braces on the appropriate lines, etc.  You also should comment your code to explain what each piece does.  It makes it **substantially** easier to debug and test when things go wrong.

Comment: Incomplete copy/paste? Post formatting it looks like you are missing a couple of braces: http://ideone.com/t8K8T

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a purpose for the array a, since it's just being completely set to true, and not used to determine what's being output.   The code you've displayed doesn't match either of the outputs you've listed, either.

Comment: yes, there was think braces missing at the end after format

Comment: I'd reformat the code for you but it feels like it is missing way too much content. Can you [edit] the post and add in the missing program?

Comment: Why do you set `a[i][j] = true` even if you print "F"?

Comment: because of the if statement "int sum = (i+j);
                               if (sum%3==0) {
                             System.out.print(   "T " );"

Comment: @user1473714 but what about `i=2` and `j=2`? In that case, `a[2][2]` is `true` but since `(2 + 2) % 3 == 1` you print `"F "`. Why not try `a[i][j] = (((i + j) % 3) == 0); if (a[i][j]) {System.out.print("T ")} else {System.out.print("F ")};`? That way your array matches your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you already print one row at a time so appending the row number to the beginning of each row (that is, before you print any values) is trivial.

As for the columns, you need to remember that `System.out` can only print left to right, not up and down. So, you need ot print the coulmn numbers before you print the rest of the array.

See my comments in this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean [][] a;
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    a = new boolean [N][N];

    System.out.print("  "); //print the spacer for the row numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
         System.out.print(i + " "); //print the column number
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<a.length;i++){ 
        System.out.print("\n" + i + " "); //new line plus row number

        for (int j = 0; j<a[0].length;j++){
            a[i][j] = true; 
            int sum = (i+j);

            if (sum%3==0) {
                System.out.print("T ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("F ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your indentation and bracket use is a bit messy (as other people have said). Look at my code. See how easy it is to see where a for loop starts and were it ends? See how easy it is to see what's inside it?

Comment: @user1473714 The important part isn't having code that works, it's having code you understand. Make sure you read through the code and understand what it's doing. That's why I put the comments in here. Never copy/paste blindly.

Comment: thank you for the tips on messy code and the braces, I usually am more neater with the braces.  I'm understand what I did wrong, or rather what I did not do.  I'm going line by line now to make sure I really got it.

Comment: "\n" is the "new line" character. It's used in pretty much all programming languages. So `System.out.print("Hello\nWorld\nHow are you?")` will print "Hello", "World" and "How are you?" on different lines.

Comment: that makes lots of sense....im thinking how I could have done this without the "\n" , command

Answer (score 3):

This code didn't produce this output (you've clearly not pasted all the code).

However, your basic problem is that you're outputting the row number *after* the row data. Change that around and you'll be a lot closer.

Output a special "heading row", and you'll be closer still.

Good luck with learning to program!

Hint: The less you ask here and try to figure out yourself, the better and faster you'll learn.